# Updating view without refreshing page

Tags: java, primefaces, render, page-refresh

I'm trying to display database tables inside dialogs using Primefaces.

each row represents a table

[image]

The Display button will open a dialog containing the db table.

The table is obtained from a HashMap (header, value).

The problem is that my table is rendered only after page refresh.

Is there a way to display the tables inside the dialog witout page refresh?

**LATER EDIT**

Here is how my dataTable from the dialog looks:

```
    <p:dataTable var="tableVar" value="#{bean.tableModel.data}">

       <p:columns var="tableHeader" value="#{bean.tableModel.headers}">
          <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="tableHeader" />
          </f:facet>

          <h:outputText value="{tableVar[tableHeader]}" />
       </p:columns>

    </p:dataTable>
```

headers from the TableModel class is an ArrayList of String and data is an ArrayList of Maps with String type keys and String type values (each map contains header-value and represents a row in the database table).

Comment: please post a code snippet

Comment: There is this thing called ajax...

Comment: I added the code snippet

Comment: Everytime you press the display button, generate the data to place in the dialog data table, right? So use update, to update that datatable inside that dialog